# send form data to server or to backend , when backend is ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

Hi im new to frontend and i know only HTML , CSS and JS . so my friend and i are doing a project which is a user panel where a manger can add users to panel. my friend wants to code backend with ASP.NET. i have made a form which is used for adding user but i dont know how to send the form data to server or to backend.

```html
<form class="addUser-from" action="" method="Post">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-dow-box">
            <label for="userName">username</label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="username" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('لطفا نام و نام خانوادگی را وارد کنید')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
            </div>
          <div class="form-dow-box">
            <label for="user-id-number">id number </label>
            <input type="text" name="user-id-number" id="user-id-number" placeholder="id number" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('لطفا کد ملی را وارد کنید')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-dow-box">
            <label for="userPass">password</label>
            <input type="password" name="userPass" id="userPass" placeholder="password" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('لطفا رمز عبور را وارد کنید')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
            </div>
         </div>
       <div class="submit-box-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="form-box-submit">add</button>
       </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: _"but i dont know how to send the form data to server or to backend"_ - add the proper receiving URL into the form `action`, and then ... click the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

You would do this through the action tag in the HTML, you would have to give it the URL of the controller you are sending it to in ASP E.G: "/user/add". Getting the data is backend from there.